# Why is half of my char array white space?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to fill a char array, but for some reason each time I hit enter it inputs Line Feed into the array, which means half of my array is LF. I tried doing fflush, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubbleSortChar( char arr[], int size);
//The instruction say to get ch *then* call binarySearchCh, so I think you
//have to add a field.
void binarySearchCh(char arr[], int size,char val,int findall); 

main()
{
    char chArray[100];
    char ch;
    int i = -1;


    while(++i<100 && scanf("%c",&chArray[i]))
        fflush(stdin);

    bubbleSortChar(chArray,100);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter a char to find.");
    scanf("%c",&ch);

    binarySearchCh(chArray,100,ch,1);


}
```

Is there a way to do this without manually removing the whitespace each time? I could do that but it seems like fflush should take care of this. This is an intro course, so it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Avoid using `main`. Use int main(void) instead.

Comment: By `<Return>`, do you mean carriage-return? It sounds like your terminal is doing the old CrLf nonsense, and line-buffering does not know that the CrLf sequence is used to represent the end-of-line. MacOS (classic), Windows and Linux all have different ideas what the [end-of-line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is supposed to be designated by.

Comment: If you aren't on Windows, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour (and probably won't clear the input buffer).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Sorry, I meant 'Line Feed'.

Comment: @haccks what is the difference between main() and main(void)?

Comment: When you declare a function as `T f ()`, it means its returns type is `T` and it can accept any number of arguments. In case of `T f (void)`, it means function is strictly expecting no arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a space before `%c` specifier to eat up the `\n` character (`<Return>`) leaving behind by `scanf` in `while` loop on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time.
Change

```
while(++i<100 && scanf("%c",&chArray[i]))
```

to

```
while(++i<100 && scanf(" %c",&chArray[i]))
```

And `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior if you are not on MS-DOS.

---

As per OP's comment;

> What if I'm at the command prompt? As far as , that's what I use for tkinter so I assumed it was the same for C. I guess what is actually being put in there is ASCII code 10, which is line feed. What is the difference between `<Return>` and `LF`?

Different operating systems have a different way of understanding new line. **Mac** only understands `\r` as new line, while **Unix** and **Linux** understand `\n` as new line character. AFAIK, Windows needs both the characters together to interpret as new line, which is `\r\n` (I am not sure about it). *This is the reason why a file created in one OS does not open properly in another OS and makes it messy*.

Comment: Thanks. It invokes undefined behavior if I'm not in DOS specifically, or Windows in general?

Comment: Oh! Yes I mean to say MS-DOS.

Comment: One thing, What do you mean by `<Return>`? Are you on MAC-OS?

Comment: What if I'm at the command prompt? 

As far as <Return>, that's what I use for tkinter so I assumed it was the same for C. I guess what is actually being put in there is ascii code 10, which is line feed. What is the difference between  <Return> and LF?

Comment: I changed '<Return>' to LF

Comment: **+1**: But I would also like to point out that this issue is hidden by format specifiers like "%d", unlike "%c" (which parses the next character, no matter whether it is whitespace or not), "%d" discards leading whitespace. You do not need this trickery with all format specifiers, it only raises its ugly head with this particular format string.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman; Yes. True. This trick is only for `%c` specifier.